# Chainring and chain compatibility for Suntour chainring

Tags: maintenance, chain, chainring, compatibility

just ordered a new chainring for my nexus-8 equipped longtail bike,
it's a suntour 48 tooth chainring shown here:
https://www.srsuntour.com/products/32-tooth-chainring?variant=27528743299

it's a 104mm 4 bolt chainring.

however I can't find specs for it anywhere - wondering if I can order a 3/32" chain (my rear sprocket spec says it works with either 1/8" or 3/32").

another thing to consider - the chain will be long (joining two chains together) as this is a longtail bike.

will the KMC Z1 (3/32") chain fit? can you recommend another?

thanks!

Comment: This is a chainring intended for front derailleur and has shifting aids that only help the chain falling off without derailleur. I'd recommend getting a singlespeed chainring instead.

Comment: thanks! I'm new to this and couldn't find chainrings to match my suntour crankset with 104BCD and 4 bolts. @ojs can you recommend an online shop that sells these? I guess when my crankset wears off I'll get a new single speed crankset...

Comment: Shopping recommendations aren't usually done here, because they are location specific and tend to be obsoleted in some time. Just googling for 104mm bcd singlespeed chainring will give you lots of options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Suntour only makes/sells derailleur cranks. So I’d guess the narrower 3/32" single speed chain should fit.